# How to make a child div full width of browser's viewport ignoring parent's position (margin & padding) and width

Tags: html, css

[This image describes the story. I want to make purple div same as green div .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MND77.png) Can someone explain me how to make a child div full width while parent's margin & padding is unknown ?

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
   </div>
</div>
```

I am mainly **stuck at adjusting child div's margin & padding.**

Note : parent div's width is margin & padding is unknown
[plz checkout the image red portion is parent and purple color is child, I want the purpule portion come out and take the full width of viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbOfN.png)

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve. `position: fixed` sets the div relative to the body, instead of the parent, maybe that helps. Else try to make your end result clearer (screenshot or example), because right now it's hard to understand what you need.

Comment: @elveti Thanks for your response. 
I have added an image , can you check this out [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MND77.png)

Here red is parent div and purple & green are child. I want to make purple div same as green div .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: 100%;` in your CSS.

```css
.child1 {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="child1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I have added an image , can you check this out [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MND77.png)

Here red is parent div and purple & green are child. I want to make purple div same as green div .

Answer (score 0):

> A [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available

If that parent container has padding, the child can still only take up the available space that is left within the content area.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FB061B;
}

.child {
  background: #7C73A5;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you know the amount of padding the parent container has, you can apply negative left & right margins (of the same amount) to the children. This is commonly seen in CSS framework grid systems.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FB061B;
  
}

.child {
  background: #7C73A5;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you don't know the parent padding but only have a single child, you can use `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0` as long as the parent is positioned.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FB061B;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: #7C73A5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child1
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when you want the child to be full screen, you can now toggle between `absolute` and `fixed` to get it from one state to the other.

```js
$(".children").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("is-fixed")
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FB061B;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.children {
  background: #7C73A5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.is-fixed {
  top: initial;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    click to toggle between absolute/fixed
    <div>child1</div>
    <div>child2</div>
    <div>child3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I have added an image , can you check this out [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MND77.png)

Here red is parent div and purple & green are child. I want to make purple div same as green div .

Comment: Ok. You need to toggle between `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` with a bit of js/jQuery. ` Check the last snippet.

Comment: great!. But in case of multiple child they are collapsing into single one . 

can you help me with this issue please :)

Comment: Put the multiple children into a common div container.

Comment: Brother I want to another child just like 

<div class="children1">
 
  </div>

<div class="children2">
 
  </div>

Comment: I feel like this question should have already been marked as answered. If you have more questions, ask another one and we will help you :)  

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask